# Subtract value of a field from a count(*) query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables:

1. `Plans(PlanID(key), Capacity)`
2. `CustomerInProject(VahedID, cinpid(key))`
3. `Vahed(VahedID(key), PlanID,...)`

This query shows number of houses with the same `PlanID` (map)  that people hired:

```
select 
    count(*) 
from
    Vahed as v2,
    CustomerInProject 
where 
    CustomerInProject.VahedID = v2.VahedID
group by PlanID
```

`Plans` has an `int` field named `Capacity`. I want to subtract `Capacity` from the above query. How can I do that?

Comment: [Avoid using old-style `JOIN` syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Can you post the table structures for the three tables. Include only the relevant columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
select p.PlanID, count(*) - p.Capacity
from Vahed as v2
join CustomerInProject c
  on c.VahedID = v2.VahedID
join Plan p
  on p.PlanID = c.PlanID /* or v.PlanID, it's not clear from the question */
group by p.PlanID, p.Capacity
```

On the 6th line, you may want to replace `c.PlanID` with `v.PlanID` - I don't know the exact table schema.

Comment: Typo, remove "where".

Answer (score 0):

```
    select sum(cnt)
    from
    (select capacity*-1  as cnt from
    plans
    union 
    select count(*)  as cnt from Vahed as v2
inner join 
      CustomerInProject  on 
        CustomerInProject.VahedID = v2.VahedID
         group by PlanID )
```